# filter data in Vue.js, but the result is always an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create an application that processes and makes a sound when there is a data update. The system will announce the ID of the updated data. I have written a program that checks the database every 1000 milliseconds and if it finds a record that has been updated within 5000 milliseconds, it sends a signal to make a sound. However, I cannot print any records that have been updated within 5000 milliseconds to the screen. There is no error message displayed in the console.

console.log(finalData.value);  // print array with many members

console.log(latestfinalData.value); //always print empty array

I expected outcome: The console.log(latestfinalData.value) should not be an empty array so that I can use it to make a sound.

This is full code

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const collection1Data = ref([]);
const collection2Data = ref([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
  const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardshows'),
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardlands'),
  ]);
  collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
  collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;
};

const finalData = ref([]);
const latestfinalData = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchData();
  setInterval(() => {
    fetchData().then(() => {
      finalData.value = [];

      collection1Data.value.forEach(doc1 => {
        const matchingDoc = collection2Data.value.find(doc2 => doc1.idshow === doc2.idshow);
        if (matchingDoc) {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc1.idshow,
            numbershow: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.numbershow : matchingDoc.numbershow,
            ab: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.ab : matchingDoc.ab,
            updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.updatedAt : matchingDoc.updatedAt
          });
        } else {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc1.idshow,
            numbershow: doc1.numbershow,
            ab: doc1.ab,
            updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt
          });
        }
      });
  
      collection2Data.value.forEach(doc2 => {
        if (!finalData.value.find(doc => doc.idshow === doc2.idshow)) {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc2.idshow,
            numbershow: doc2.numbershow,
            ab: doc2.ab,
            updatedAt: doc2.updatedAt
          });
        }
      });

      console.log(finalData.value);


      latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => doc.updatedAt >= (Date.now() - 5000));
      console.log(latestfinalData.value);
    });
  }, 1000);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Try with changing lines of code and check it works.
`const updatedAtInMs = Date.parse(doc.updatedAt);`
`latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => Date.parse(doc.updatedAt) >= (Date.now() - 5000));`

Comment: const updatedAtInMs = Date.parse(doc.updatedAt); 
     Hi NIKUNJ KOTHIYA
 latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => Date.parse(doc.updatedAt) >= (Date.now() - 5000));
      console.log(latestfinalData.value); // still get empty array

Comment: [
    {
        "idshow": 1,
        "numbershow": 1038,
        "ab": "L",
        "updatedAt": "2023-02-07T06:36:18.991Z"
    },
    {
        "idshow": 2,
        "numbershow": 168,
        "ab": "B",
        "updatedAt": "2023-02-07T06:36:16.595Z"
    },

Comment: it still empty so I post data of finalData.value

Comment: latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => (Date.now() - new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime()) < 5000); I try this one it work

Comment: Cheers Man! you got your solution and learn something from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this line of code of OP solutions:

```
latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => (Date.now() - new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime()) < 5000);
```